# Snipmate warning snipmate.vim already defined

Tags: vim, warnings, defined, snipmate

How can I get rid of this annoying error message occuring everytime I open vim?:

```
Warning in snipMate.vim: Snippet c) is already defined. See :h multi_snip for help on snippets with multiple matches.
```

I tried to install snipmate by

```
 % cd ~/.vim/bundle
 % git clone https://github.com/tomtom/tlib_vim.git
 % git clone https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils.git
 % git clone https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate.git
 % git clone https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets.git
```

However, snipmate did not work, so I deleted these directories(including all files in it) with

```
rm -rf {directories}
```

then tried to install it again using a different source after Google found me a different site how to install, thinking it's fine...

```
cd ~/.vim
mv snippets snippets.orig
git clone git://github.com/scrooloose/snipmate-snippets.git snippets
```

I think I have to uninstall the old files, but I dont know how.
I tried to open `:h multi_snip` in vim but nothing happens.

Comment: What do you mean by "I think"? You don't know what plugins you use and whhich does what?

Comment: I did use pathogen. Sorry

Comment: How do you know that snipmate didn't work after the first installation? What were the tests that you performed to see if it was working?

Comment: The tab key does not work

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you uninstall deleted files installed by git clone command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253573/how-do-you-uninstall-deleted-files-installed-by-git-clone-command)

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the vim plugins and mainly you have to **clean** the folder.

If you are using [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) to manage plugins you can run this command to remove duplicates, unused plugins etc:

```
vim +BundleClean +qall
```

Comment: This is not ideal, it just removes what I'm no longer using in my `.vimrc` file

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is simple, add the following line to your `.vimrc`

```
    let g:snipMate = { 'snippet_version' : 1 }
```

This will use the new parser in SnipMate.

This is now in the notice for `:h SnipMate-deprecate`.