# How do you uninstall deleted files installed by git clone command?

Tags: macos, git, vim, snipmate

I heard about the awesomeness of **`vim`**, so naturally I said "vim me up". After, countless Youtube videos and Googling for hours, I was ready to install my pluggins ( so I thought). I was able to install **`NERDTree`** thru **`Pathogen`** and I was feeling good about myself since I'm new to **`Mac(OSX 10.9)`** and coding in general. So, I then proceeded to install the next pluggin **`Snipmate`** using instructions from https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate

```
% cd ~/.vim/bundle
% git clone https://github.com/tomtom/tlib_vim.git
% git clone https://github.com/MarcWeber/vim-addon-mw-utils.git
% git clone https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate.git
% git clone https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets.git
```

Snipmate did not work. So, I deleted these directories by rm -rf {directories} 
then tried to install it again using instructions from http://spf13.com/post/vim-plugins-snipmate this time

```
cd ~/.vim
mv snippets snippets.orig
git clone git://github.com/scrooloose/snipmate-snippets.git snippets
```

Maybe I shouldn't have done since I now have these errors everytime I open vim.

```
Warning in snipMate.vim: Snippet c) is already defined. See :h multi_snip for help on snippets with multiple matches.
Warning in snipMate.vim: Snippet date is already defined. See :h multi_snip for help on snippets with multiple matches.
Warning in snipMate.vim: Snippet ddate is already defined. See :h multi_snip for help on snippets with multiple matches.
```

Do you think if I could uninstall those files, that I had deleted, would it rid of these errors and maybe snipmate would work?
How do you uninstall git clone command? Am I right in thinking these?

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but I recommend [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim) over Pathogen as plugin manager for Vim.

Comment: Try undoing what you did: do `cd ~/.vim` then `rm -rf snippets` then `mv snippets.orig snippets`. Do you still get warning when you start Vim after doing that?

Comment: Thank you Jubobs! That did it hahaha. I'm so happy I wont see those errors again

Comment: If I do it with Vundle do you think I will run into the same problem if I try to reinstall snipMate again?

Comment: I just followed the instructions on https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate to install SnipMate with Vundle. Then I closed and reopened Vim (no warnings), saved a file with a `c` extension, typed `for` followed by <Tab>, and the advertised snippet appeared. I'd say the Vundle instructions are safe. Try it out for yourself and report.

Comment: i just installed `Vundle` then run `:BundleInstall` in `vim` then it prompted me to `Username for https://github.com:` is it asking me to create a github account bec I don't have one, or is it asking for someone else's who has the files I want? Thanks again

Comment: Are you sure you entered the correct github repository? Vundle should prompt you for username and password if the repository you are trying to access does not exist. Make sure you copied it exactly from the snipmate website.

Comment: @Zach & @Jubobs thank you. Do you think this is bec I left out the code `execute pathogen#infect()` at the buttom of the `.vimrc`? I left that out bec I was thinking the NERDTree was already installed by `Pathogen` therefore maybe it requires it. Am I wrong? Or should I just use `Vundle` for everything? If yes should I uninstall `NERDTREE` first before reinstalling it with vundle?  My `/.vim/bundle` directory has `L9`, `Vundle.vim`, `command-t`, `nerdtree`, `snipmate.vim`, `sparkup` & `vim-fugitive`

Comment: Ok, first of all, NERDTree has nothing to do with NERDCommenter (except that they were made by the same guy). Second, if you are using pathogen, then you should put `execute pathogen#infect()` at the top of you vimrc, not the bottom. Don't combine pathogen and Vundle. Use one or the other but not both. With the setup you have right now I would recommend you go with pathogen (its what I use and I have snipmate working perfectly).

Comment: @Zach are some of these files in my bundle directory points to NERDCommenter? Bec that is not my intention. I installed NERDTree by pathogen initially then snipMate but snipMate did not work, I don't believe I mentioned NERDCommenter anywhere. Is NERDCommenter another pluggin?

Comment: Whoops! I just got mixed up with another question, no I meant Snipmate has nothing to do with NERDTree. And yes NERDCommenter is another plugin. Its a plugin for auto commenting out lines of code for you. You can check it out but I think the plugin tcomment is better for that purpose.

Comment: @Jubobs I followed your advise and learn `vundle` thru [www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-vundle-to-manage-vim-plugins-on-a-linux-vps] and was able to install snipmate. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

That's because you still have the snippets defined in "snippets.orig". If you delete the folder (or if you want to keep it move it to a directory outside of .vim) and you should be fine.

Comment: thanks. Are you responding to why am I getting the warnings or is this response about why am I being asked to enter username for `github.com`?

Comment: Hi @kofi - I was answering to why you got the warning. You did not mention that you were asked for the username. However, I know why you had to give your username. When you clone using "git clone https://xxxx", you need to authenticate manually. Using "git clone git://xxxx", you will be authenticated using SSH. See the [Github documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use) for more information on that. If the answer helps, please upvote(;